# Ajax not being called in javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In the success function I want to call a function. The problem is that ajax does not fire, so the data is never triggered and display. Here is my ajax call with a javascript function call in the success function.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./api/login.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        if(data){
            //FUNCTION CALL WHEN USER LOGGING IN
            retrieveUserBlogData();

            window.location = "api/home.php";
        }else{
            $('.alert').show();

        }
    }
});

function retrieveUserBlogData(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'retrievePostData.php',          
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',      
        success: handleData
    });
}

function handleData(data) {
    alert(data);

    var blog_file = data[3];            
    $('#imageDiv')
    .append('<img id="blog_img" src="upload/' +     blog_file + '"><br>');
}
```

I cant figure out why the ajax in the retrieveUserBlogData() function is not being triggered.
Any help would be appreciated Thanks.

Comment: i think the problem is with 'window.location = "api/home.php"'. Because you are changing the page before the success event of second ajax call,.

Answer (score 4):

Even if the AJAX succeeds, you are redirecting the browser to a different page after the first AJAX request:

```
window.location = "api/home.php";
```

So I would suggest removing that.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code for redirecting to another window

```
window.location.assign(URL);
```

then it may work.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./api/login.php",
data: dataString,
cache: false,
success: function(data){
    if(data){
        //FUNCTION CALL WHEN USER LOGGING IN
        retrieveUserBlogData();            
    }else{
        $('.alert').show();

    }
 }
});

function retrieveUserBlogData(){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'retrievePostData.php',          
    data: "",
    dataType: 'json',      
    success: function(data){
        alert(data);

        var blog_file = data[3];            
        $('#imageDiv')
        .append('<img id="blog_img" src="upload/' +     blog_file + '"><br>');

        window.location = "api/home.php";
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Try moving the entire ajax call from the retrieveUserBlogData() function to the if(data) condition from the first ajax call, and in the succes from the second call  use console.log() to see the response obj if there is any